# Unit testing DateTime strings

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime, cultureinfo

I have a class that converts a `string` into a `DateTime` and perform some business logic in it:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string value)
    {
        Value = DateTime.Parse(value);
    }

    public DateTime Value { get; }

    // Some additional methods
}
```

I would like to unit test `Foo` so that it only accepts valid datetime `string`s, so I wrote a unit test:

```
public class FooTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Foo_ValidDateTimeString_Returns()
    {
        const string testInput = "2015-01-01";

        var result = new Foo(testInput);

        var expected = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
        Assert.Equal(expected, result.Value);
    }
}
```

This test passes in various cultures such as en-US.

My concern is, this unit test will fail when another colleague who is under a different `CultureInfo` which does not accept `yyyy-MM-dd` as a valid `DateTime` format.

I do not want to enforce the test to be run under a specific `CultureInfo` in order to make the test pass. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as argument to `Parse()` method

```
    Value = DateTime.Parse(value,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

so that you don't have to care about culture inside unit-tests. 
Another way, if you want to keep data as-is the other way is to go for exact parsing

```
   Value = DateTime.ParseExact(value,"yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: But my intention for Foo is to respect the developer's CurrentCulture and give what they expect (in their local culture), thus I do not want to use ParseExact or the Parse(string, IFormatProvider) overload. Is there another way?

Comment: @rexcfnghk If you assume they provide correct input then parsing with implicit culture (CurrentCulture) should be fine. However, if you enter date on one machine and parse it on other when culture may be different then you need to enforce some standards.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to enforce the test to be run under a specific
>   CultureInfo in order to make the test pass. Is there another way?

#### No.

Using the `CurrentCulture` on the system is *usually* a bad idea, because the string that you provided can mean different things for different culture settings.

For example; `2015-01-02` can mean 1st February or 2nd January for different cultures with using `DateTime.Parse(string)` overload.

`DateTime.ParseExact` with a *specific* culture is a much more detailed, controlled and exact approach.

This stated in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as well;

> Because the `Parse(String)` method tries to parse the string
>   representation of a date and time using the formatting rules of the
>   current culture, trying to parse a particular string across different
>   cultures **can either fail or return different results**. If a specific
>   date and time format will be parsed across different locales, **use the
>   DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider) method or one of the overloads
>   of the ParseExact method and provide a format specifier**.

Comment: But my intention for `Foo` is to respect the developer's `CurrentCulture` and give what they expect (in their local culture), thus I do not want to use `ParseExact` or the `Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` overload. Is there another way?

Comment: @rexcfnghk No, as I said, there is **no** safe way to do it. Why don't you wanna use `ParseExact` by the way? Is there any special reason?

Comment: There are no special reasons. It's just my design intention to support this as the API, i.e. if an American developer enters `02-01-2015`, that should mean `1st February, 2015`; if a British developer enters the same value, it will mean `2nd January, 2015`. To clarify I don't really care about the **actual date** entered because it is only used for some business calculation. I want my API to simply respect the developers' `CultureInfo` to perform calculation on a date they expect

Comment: @rexcfnghk If you don't _care_ the parsed `DateTime` value, maybe you shouldn't parse it _at all_. If so, just use `DateTime.TryParse` which takes `string[]` as a formats and use `{"yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-dd-MM"}` formats available. Then you will not worry the _real_ value of your `DateTime`. You just check it can be parse or not. Don't worry by the way. There is _only_ 1 culture (Arabic - Saudi Arabia as `ar-SA`) which can't parse this `2015-01-01` in `CultureTypes.AllCultures`. But _still_, this sounds a bad approach to me.